# Acquiring WiFi wakelock does not keep WiFi alive on Android device

Tags: java, android, android-service, wifi, wifimanager

I am developing an app which has a service which continuously uploads something for which it needs to use WiFi. When I turn the screen off, after about half an hour, the app stops uploading. Turning the screen on, I can see that the WiFi is not connected, and it reconnects within a few seconds. I believe the WiFi is going to sleep.

To prevent the WiFi from going to sleep, I acquire a WiFi wakelock. However, this seems to make no difference and the WiFi goes to sleep still. What am I doing wrong and how can I keep the WiFi alive? I am acquiring the wakelock like below:

```
public MyService extends Service{
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "LockTag");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                wifiLock.acquire();
                while(True){
                    uploadFiles();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                wifiLock.release();


            }

        }.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```